# Getting attribute of repeated control from JSF managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, components

I'm using JSF + Primefaces on Websphere trying to create a stickies-like app.

I have a hard time getting attributes (style for position in this case) from repeated controls, when using onDrop listener. Here is my code:

`board.xhtml`

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:dataList id="restPanel" styleClass="restrictPanel" var="note"
        value="#{publicBoard.getNotes()}" columns="1" type="none">
        <p:panel id="note" header="#{note.title}" styleClass="smallNote"
            style="#{publicBoard.getNoteStyle(note)}">
            <h:outputText value="#{note.description}" />
        </p:panel>

        <p:draggable for="note" containment="parent" opacity="0.3" />
    </p:dataList>

    <p:droppable for="mainForm" datasource="restPanel">
        <p:ajax process="@form" listener="#{publicBoard.onDrop}" />
    </p:droppable>
</h:form>
```

`publicBoard` bean

```
public void onDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
    Note obj = (Note) ddEvent.getData();

    System.out.println("NOTE ID:" + obj.getId());
    System.out.println(ddEvent.getDragId());
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent(ddEvent.getDragId());
    if(component!=null){
    System.out.println(component.getId());
    }else{
        System.out.println("NULL COMPONENT");
    }
}
```

Result

```
[22.07.15 14:27:16:094 CEST] 000000c8 SystemOut     O NOTE ID:4
[22.07.15 14:27:16:094 CEST] 000000c8 SystemOut     O mainForm:restPanel:3:note
[22.07.15 14:27:16:094 CEST] 000000c8 SystemOut     O NULL COMPONENT
```

Any help will be appreciated!